# How to open an item in content editor immediately after creation

Tags: asp.net, command, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have created command template for item creation. I followed the steps which are mentioned in below link  http://techblogsearch.com/a/example-of-sitecore-command-template-with-user-interface.html

I want to open that created item in content editor with Expanded content tree, as default item creation works.

How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/open-content-editor-on-specific-item.html ?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Does the steps you followed works? If yes, the item will automatically show and open in the content editor. What is the current issue?

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak but these options didnt worked as i wanted to open the item  in same link.....  But I got the solution by doing  
 string load = String.Concat(new object[] { "item:load(id=", openItem.ID.ToString(), ",language=", openItem.Language.ToString(), ")" });
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load);